# CodeIgniter Multiple Row Update

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with a project of mine. I have read around and have no idea on what to do any more. This is a Codeigniter todo list project for our small office. I have made the displaying the contents of the database part already however I'm stumped on the updating part. On the view part, there's a todo list with checkboxes.  If they are completed with the task, then they check the box and then put in the date when they did it and their initials.  So they can check a lot of tasks and put dates and initials and I'm having a problem updating them in one time. I'm stumped. Please help. Thanks!

**Controller**

```
public function update_tasks() {
    $this->load->model('model_members');        
    $post=$this->input->post();
    $this->model_memberdashboard->reset_tasks($this->session->userdata('UserID')); // resets completion status of all tasks since checkboxes that are not checked doesn't do Post
    foreach ($post['checkbox'] as $row){
        $newData = array(
            'completed'=> 1
        );
        $this->model_members->update_tasks($newData,$row);
    }
    $this->index();
```

**Model**

```
  public function update_tasks($data,$id) {
        $this->db->update("mastertaskslist",$data,['id' => $id]);
    }
```

**View**  <- Im using bootstrap so its a bit long

```
foreach ($allowedTasklist_1 as $row) {                                    
    echo '<li class="ui-state-default clearfix">';
    echo '<div class=row>';
        echo '<div class="col-sm-1">';
            $checkbox=array(
                'name'        => 'checkbox[]',
                'id'          => 'checkbox[]',
                'type'        => 'checkbox',                                                
                'value'       => $row->id,
                'checked'     => $row->completed,                                     
            );
            if ($row->completed=="False"){
                unset($checkbox['checked']);                        
            }                                            
            echo form_checkbox($checkbox);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-sm-1">';
            echo '<label>'.$num.'.'.'</label>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-sm-10">';
            echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';
                    echo '<p>'.$row->taskTitle.'</p>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-8">';
                    if ($row->lastUpdate=='0000-00-00'){
                        $currDate=NULL;                                                
                    }   else {
                        $currDate=date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row->lastUpdate));
                    }
                    $date=array(
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'class'       => 'datepicker',
                        'name'        => 'date['.$row->id.']',
                        'id'          => 'date['.$row->id.']',                                                        
                        'value'       => $currDate,
                        'placeholder' => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                        'size'        => '15'
                    );
                    echo form_input($date);                                              
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
                $initials=array(
                    'name'        => 'initials['.$row->id.']',
                    'id'          => 'initials[]',
                    'value'       => $row->initials,
                    'maxlength'   => '100',
                    'size'        => '3',
                );                                    
                echo form_input($initials);
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';                                        
    echo '</div>';
    $num++;
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: use a batch query for multiple update https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update

Comment: @RakeshSharma website for codeigniter user guide now is http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/ new owners of CI

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I tried using update_batch and I only got it working using the controller and model.  Im really confused on how to pass the post array variable into the controller so that it will be passed to the model.  Here's what I did to view the post array

Comment: $post=$this->input->post();        
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($post);      
        echo '</pre>';
 }

Array Result from the form containing (Checkbox, Date Field, Text Field).  I already assigned Ids to each from View.  I wish I could give you more. Im just starting using CI.  Thanks!

Comment: Array
(
    [form_update] => Update
    [checkbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 405
            [1] => 406
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [405] => 02/05/2014
            [406] => 01/05/2015
            [407] => 
            [408] => 
            [409] => 
            [410] => 
            [411] => 
            [412] => 
        )

    [initials] => Array
        (
            [405] => sdfasdf
            [406] => asdfasdf
            [407] => 
            [408] => 
            [409] => 
            [410] => 
            [411] => 
            [412] => 
        )
)